# Selenium: Unable to upload a File from the local Directory of Java Project in Intellij

Tags: java, selenium

```
System.out.println("LC13.2 started");
                //Locate the element name 'Dokument Auswahlen'
                WebElement DokUpload = driver.findElement(By.xpath(property.getProperty("DokumentSelection_ButtonXpath")));
                String FilePath = ".\\resources\\SyncPilot_Showformular_Testing.pdf";
                DokUpload.sendKeys(FilePath);
```

Above Code trying to locate an Element and upload a File from the Local Directory of Project in Intellij but it is failing.
Any Suggestion how to do it?[image]

Comment: Try /resources/SyncPilot_Showformular_Testing.pdf?

Comment: It is not working!

Answer (score 0):

Uploading files using sendKeys expect absolute path , we are sending the location not the file . So when it reaches the front end current directory won't be your selenium current directory .. So there won't be any file in that path

Use path builder to create absolute path

`System.getProperty("user.home") + /file/relativepath/file.pdf`

Comment: By using above line of code, getting error JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.

Comment: Try user.dir instead of user.home

Comment: i did that, and when opening the printed path in chrome, it is opening the file but it is showing same error.

Comment: No i think that line refers to the JavaScript library, it is not related to the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225165/discussion-between-shivam-goyal-and-pdhide).